# How do I get rows from 3 days last login and longer

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to code a feature for my service that I have and I'm sort of struggling to get it to work..

I basically want to code a function where it logs where people haven't logged in for 3 or more days, but it just won't work.

I currently have:

```
$findActivity = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'last_active' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 3 DAY");
while($activeRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findActivity)){
    
    $usr = $activeRow['username'];;
    $la = $activeRow['last_active'];

    echo "<tr class='row100 body'>";
    echo "<td class='cell100 column3'>$usr</td>";
    echo "<td class='cell100 column3'>$inactivefor</td>";
    echo "<td class='cell100 column3'>$msg</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I basically want it to output results where it will display accounts that have not logged in for 3 or more days.

Comment: Won't work how? You get an error? Unexpected result? Please be specific. And provide sample data and expected output please too, so we can be 100% clear what's required. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: You say 7 days in the question title and 3 in the question, please be consistent.

Comment: 3 or more days (sorry I was testing 7 at the time and got a bit mixed up). Basically the output result it comes up as no result - like no results are coming back from the code. I've edited the original post to contain the proper code (sql - printing results)

Comment: Again, we need some sample source data so we can understand if that would be expected or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$findActivity = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_active < 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 3 DAY");
while ($activeRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findActivity)) {
$usr = $activeRow['username'];
$la = $activeRow['last_active'];

echo "<tr class='row100 body'>";
echo "<td class='cell100 column3'>$usr</td>";
echo "<td class='cell100 column3'>$la</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

}